# CodeIgniter not injecting/refreshing Browser

Tags: codeigniter

Using Sublimetext 2 and CodeIgniter, 
Everything was working find then all of a sudden css files stopped reloading/refreshing in browser.

I edited some php files in the project and that worked fine, but for some reason not css files.

Comment: Are you sure the browser isn't caching the CSS?

Comment: Will check, tried both browsers. It's weird that it all of a sudden mid work

Comment: Try getting the CSS file directly rather than through a page served by CI. Likely CI isn't the cause of the problem, but there's a chance I suppose.

Comment: could you try to delete temporary files in your browser.

Comment: you can add some query string so that browser never cache e.g `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_css.css?v=<?php echo time() ?>">`

Comment: Yeah, i cleared and disabled cache, and not dice. PHP files are working fine, just not css.

Comment: I created a new project with ONE html file and One css file and still not css injeciton